# How to get custom attribute value with product id of enable product with SQL query in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, database, sql

How to get custom attribute value with product id of enabled product with SQL query in Magento 2?

I am using

```
SELECT entity_id,value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 150
```

But it gives me all data I want these data only to enable products.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
select
    A.entity_id,A.value
from
    catalog_product_entity_varchar A
inner join catalog_product_entity_int B
    on A.entity_id = B.entity_id
where
    B.attribute_id = 97 and B.value = 2  and A.attribute_id=73
```

in **catalog_product_entity_int** you have information about status (in my case it is attribute with id = 97). `value == 2` means product is disabled and `value == 1` means product is enabled. Above code will return disabled products with attribute 73 value.

Comment: Thanks for your response 
I have used 

select
    A.entity_id,A.value
from
    catalog_product_entity_varchar A
inner join catalog_product_entity_int B
    on A.entity_id = B.entity_id
where
    B.attribute_id = 97 and B.value = 1  and A.attribute_id=150

as 150 is my attribute id but it returns me enabled and disabled both on changeing value to 2 it returns me correct result 
Why it is return both enabled and disabled on value = 1

Comment: It works with adding store_id value in query thanks for that.

Will you please help me with this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323363/filter-is-not-working-on-custom-values-in-magento-2-order

Comment: Glat to hear it works for you!   
I will look at this after my work :D But not sure what is wrong, never did filtering by custom value...

Comment: okk please look if you have time i have struck in this around 2 days but not getting any solution and again thanks for the help.